# Register custom class in assembly with web project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using web project and web forms.

I create Custom Class

```
 Namespace CustomWebControls
  Public Class NoValidationDDL
    Inherits DropDownList


  End Class
End Namespace
```

and i try to register this class in assembly web.config page section

```
<controls>
        <add tagPrefix="customDDL" namespace="CustomWebControls" assembly="ae" />
</controls>
```

and try to use in ascx

```
<customDDL:NoValidationDDL ID ="id" runat="server"></customDDL:NoValidationDDL>
```

How can i do this in web project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (assuming the assembly name for your project is `ae`) - make sure that you build the project after creating/modifying your custom control. Unless updated 'ae.dll' is present in your bin directory, intellisense etc will not work.

Instead of modify web.config, you may also try register control at page(aspx) or control(ascx) level by adding register directive after page directive:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="ae" Namespace="CustomWebControls" TagPrefix="customDDL" %>
```

Comment: Yes but I have one problem here. Because I using web project(File -- New Web Site) in bin I don't have assembly dll of project. This is not web application where I have in Properties AssemblyInfo.vb file. Maybe I can create new project (Server Control or other type and put refrence in this project).

Comment: @ziks, so its a web site project! But from where the assembly name 'ae' come from? In web site projects, the assembly name would be a generated one. You have to either package your custom control in a separate assembly (project) or use web application project.